# I keep getting a error with this program. After getting the date in the compiler the error prompts and I'm unsure as to how to fix it

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner

This is what I have to do for an assignment

> Design a class named Account that contains:
>
> A private int data field named id for the account (default 0).
>
> A private double data field named balance for the account (default 0).
>
> A private double data field named annualInterestRate that stores the
> current interest rate (default 0). Assume all accounts have the same
> interest rate.
>
> A private Date data field named dateCreated that stores the date when
> the account was created.
>
> A no-arg constructor that creates a default account.
>
> A constructor that creates an account with the specified id and
> initial balance.
>
> The accessor and mutator methods for id, balance, and
> annualInterestRate.
>
> The accessor method for dateCreated.
>
> A method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly
> interest rate.
>
> A method named getMonthlyInterest() that returns the monthly interest.
>
> A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the
> account.
>
> A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the
> account.
>
> Implement the class. (Hint: The method getMonthlyInterest() is to
> return monthly interest, not the interest rate. Monthly interest is
> balance * monthlyInterestRate. monthlyInterestRate is
> annualInterestRate / 12. Note that annualInterestRate is a percentage,
> e.g., like 4.5%. You need to divide it by 100.)
>
> Write a test program that creates an Account object with an account ID
> of 1122, a balance of $20,000, and an annual interest rate of 4.5%.
> Use the following transactions (negative values are withdrawals,
> positive values are deposits). I would like to see the transactions
> stored in a file.
>
> ```
> -100.00
> 250.00
> 650.00
> -25.00
> 10.00
> -50.00
> -60.00
> -80.00
> 100.00
> ```
>
> Print the balance, the monthly interest, and the date when this
> account was created. Calculate the interest based upon the ending
> balance at the end of the month, you should include the interest in
> your final balance.

What I have so far is listed below. Any help would be appreciated. The error is listed after the code as comments.
Below is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

//Account
class Account
{
//variables
private int id;
private double balance;
private double annualInterest;
private Date dateCreated;

 //default constuctor
Account(){}

//constructor
Account(int i,double bal){
this.id=i;
this.balance=bal;
}
//set Id
public void setId(int i)
{
this.id=i;
}
//set Balance
public void setBalance(double bal)
{
this.balance=bal;
}
//set InterestRate
public void setInterestRate(double rate)
{
this.annualInterest=rate;
}


//get ID
public int getId()
{
return id;
}
//get Balance
public double getBalance()
{
return balance;
}
 //get InterestRate(
public double getInterestRate()
{
return annualInterest;
}
//get Date
public Date getDate()
{
dateCreated=new Date();
return dateCreated;
}
//get MonthlyInterestRate
public double getMonthlyInterestRate()
{
double monthlyInterest=getMonthlyInterest();
return balance*monthlyInterest;
}
//get MonthlyInterest
public double getMonthlyInterest()
{
return (annualInterest/1200);
}
//withdraw
public void withdraw(double amt)
{
this.balance=balance-amt;
}
//deposit
public void deposit(double amt)
{
this.balance=balance+amt;
}
}
//main method
public class AccountDriver {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

//set account id, balance 
Account at=new Account(1122,20000);

//set InterestRate
at.setInterestRate(4.5);


System.out.println("ID: "+at.getId());
System.out.println("Balance: "+at.getBalance());
System.out.println("Interest: "+at.getInterestRate());
System.out.println("Date: "+at.getDate().toString());


//transaction
Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("c:\\books\\trans.txt"));

while(sc.hasNext())
{
int amt=sc.nextInt();
if(amt<0)
at.withdraw(amt);
else
at.deposit(amt);
}
//print balance
System.out.println("Balance After Trasaction: ");
System.out.println("Balance: "+at.getBalance());
System.out.println("Interest Rate: "+at.getMonthlyInterestRate());

}

}

//The error I keep receiving is below. 
//Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
//at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
//at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
//at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
//at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
//at Personal_Projects.AccountDriver.main(AccountDriver.java:107)
```

Comment: Please provide the contents of the trans.txt file. The error you're getting points at the file containing something that can't be parsed as an integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading data from file  "c:\books\trans.txt".

According to your code,

```
while(sc.hasNext()) {
     int amt=sc.nextInt();
     if(amt<0)
        at.withdraw(amt);
     else
        at.deposit(amt);
}
```

You are only reading integers from the files, means files should be like this

```
1
2
3
4
```

And so on, no any string or comma or anything, if there is any other string or comma it will throw the exception. You can resolve the error by using **sc.hasNextInt()** in while loop.

** Solution**

```
while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
     int amt=sc.nextInt();
     if(amt<0)
        at.withdraw(amt);
     else
        at.deposit(amt);
}
```

Comment: Cant tell you how helpful this is. Thank you a great deal.

Comment: Welcome, please accept the answer, if it helpful for you. :)